# Shrinking an allocated physical disk size in VMWare Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I got a VMWare image that it's hard disk was allocated when creating.

Isn't there any way to shrink it? Tried using the VM Settings but got this error: `You can't compact this virtual disk because it is preallocated.`. VM command also can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [VMware](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_vdiskmanager_ws.html) you can use the Virtual Disk Manager utility in VMware Workstation to change the disk type.  This utility runs through the command line, not the GUI.